# error on a ajax request with python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I've got a html file with following lines of code

```
<script>
function ButClick(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../cgi-bin/test.py",
        type: "POST",
        data: {var1: 'Value 1', var2: 'Value 2'},
        success: function(response){$("#TestDiv").html(response);}
    })
}
</script>

<form><input type='button' onclick="ButClick()" value="Click Me!" /></form>
<div id='TestDiv'></div>
```

and I've got a Python 3.4 script in test.py:

```
#![...]/custom/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
data=cgi.FieldStorage()
print("Var1-Data lautet: " + data['var1'].value)
```

I just want to perform an ajax reqest when clicking the button. But I'll getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 12, in &lt;module&gt;
print("Var1-Data lautet: " + data['var1'].value)
File "[...]/custom/lib/python3.4/cgi.py", line 598, in __getitem__ raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'var1'
```

Can anybody please help me to find the error?

Comment: Did you try dumping `data` to the console in the python?

Comment: I havn't used python that much but I think if u change `data['var1'].value` to `data.getvalue('var1')` it should be ok

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti javascript will accept non-quoted names in json as long as they are valid js identifiers

Comment: @ThinkDifferent His code looks like the example at the beginning of https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html

Comment: @ThinkDifferent sorry, this also won't work...

Comment: @ThinkDifferent: i checked the link you posted. Yes you're right. It looks like the example shown there... But I'm not able to take a solution for my problem out of the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now, I found myself a solution to my problem. There I, do not use CGI but PHP an Pyton. Certainly, this solution is not very elegant, but it does what I want. In addition, I must perform some MySQL queries. All in all I can by the way increase the performance of the whole page.

My Code now looks like this:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
      function ButClick(){
      var TestVar = "'Hallo! This is a test'";
      $.post('test.php',{var:TestVar},function(response) $('#TestDiv').html(response)});
    }
</script>

    <form><input type='button' onclick="ButClick()" value="Click Me!" /></form>
    <div id='TestDiv'></div>  </body>

</body>


</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php
$param1=$_POST['var'];
$command="python test.py $param1 $param2";  
$buffer='';
ob_start(); // prevent outputting till you are done
passthru($command);

$buffer=ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo "PHP and".$buffer;

?>
```

test.py

```
#path to your python interpreter
#!/usr/bin/python   
#sys module to get access to the passed in parameters
import sys
# the first parameters in sys.argv[0] is the path to the current executing python script
param1=sys.argv[1]
PyAnswer="python back: " +param1
# send the result back to php
print (PyAnswer)
```

I hope, that I can help with these post some other people!